# Cant query custom meta box values to display codes

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

Im having trouble querying posts that I want to from a dropdown metabox in the posts.. I eventually aim to create metaboxes for featured post 1, 2, 3 etc but need to know how to get these to display. Any help? thanks

```
     // ADD ALL OUR META BOX STUFF
     add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'voodoo_meta_box');

     function voodoo_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('voodoo_title_link', 'Link Format Title URL', 'voodoo_title_link',      'post', 'side', 'default');
     }

     // SET UP THE TITLE LINK META BOX
     function voodoo_title_link() { 
    global $post; 

    // NONCENAME NEEDED TO VERIFY WHERE THE DATA ORIGINATED 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="voodoo_meta_noncename" id="voodoo_meta_noncename" value="' . 
        wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />'; 

    // GET EXISTING DATA IF IT'S ALREADY BEEN ENTERED
    $voodoo_dropdown = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'voodoo_dropdown', true);

?>
<fieldset id="voodoo-div">
<div>
<p>
     <label for="voodoo_dropdown" >Dropdown Options:</label><br />
     <select name="voodoo_dropdown" id="voodoo_dropdown">
     <option<?php selected( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'voodoo_dropdown', true), 'USA' ); ?                            >>USA</option>
<option<?php selected( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'voodoo_dropdown', true), 'Canada' ); ?>>Canada</option>
<option<?php selected( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'voodoo_dropdown', true), 'Mexico' ); ?>>Mexico</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>
<?php
}

     // GOTTA SAVE THE METADATA OF COURSE
          function voodoo_save_meta($post_id, $post) { 

    // CHECK THIS CAME FROM THE RIGHT SCREEN WITH PROPER AUTHENTICATION 
    // SINCE SAVE POST CAN BE TRIGGERED OTHER WAYS
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['voodoo_meta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ))     { 
    return $post->ID; 
    } 

    // CAN WE EDIT THE POST OR PAGE? 
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )) 
        return $post->ID; 

    // AFTER AUTHENTICATION WE NEED TO FIND AND SAVE THE DATA
    // PUT IT IN AN ARRAY TO MAKE IT EASIER TO LOOP THROUGH

    $voodoo_meta['voodoo_dropdown'] = $_POST['voodoo_dropdown'];

    // ADD VALUES OF $voodoo_meta AS CUSTOM FIELDS

    foreach ($voodoo_meta as $key => $value) { // LOOP THROUGH THE $voodoo_meta ARRAY! 
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // DON'T STORE THE DATA TWICE
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // IF $value IS IN AN ARRAY, MAKE IT A CSV (unlikely) 
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // IF CUSTOM FIELD ALREADY HAS A VALUE 
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value); 
        } else { // AND IF IT DOESN'T ALREADY HAVE A VALUE 
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value); 
        } 
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // DELETE IF IT'S EMPTY 
    } 

     } 

     add_action('save_post', 'voodoo_save_meta', 1, 2); // SAVE THE CUSTOM FIELDS
```

PHP ON HOME PAGE

```
<?php

  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'meta_key' => 'voodoo_meta',
    'meta_value' => 'Canada',
    'showposts' => 1
  );

  $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>

        <div id="listing-container">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="listing-ftimg"><div class="postborder"></div><div class="posteximgzoom"></div><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'blog-posts' ); ?></div></a>

            <div class="listing-title"><h12><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_titlesmall('', '...', true, '50') ?></a></h12></div>

            <div class="favourite-post">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="date-cat-post"><span class="datehomelisting"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> ·&nbsp;</span><span class="categoryhomelisting"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span></div>

            <div class="excerpt-post">

            <p class="excerptlisting"><?php echo excerpt(40); ?></p>

            </div>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="readmorebutton"><span class="readmorep">Read More</span></div></a>


        </div>


      <div class="seplisting"></div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: no posts are showing on the front end..

Comment: Your query `$args` look fine. Can you be sure there are posts in the database with a `voodoo_meta` meta key and a value of `Canada`?

Comment: What is `the_titlesmall`? Should that be `the_title`?

Comment: Thats the thing I dont know if these meta keys and values have been assigned to the post. Did you have a look at the first piece of code I provided? Yes the_titlesmall is an excerpt title. Thats working fine

Comment: If voodoo_meta and Canada haven't been assigned to a post then you will have zero results returned.

Comment: How can I make sure they are assigned? I have marked them on edit post but is that code right? Thanks for ur help so far

Comment: You'll need to check in the database. The table you need to check is called `wp_postmeta`. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for the database description. You will need to use something like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)